# http://localhost:8000/token/ 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

in django, i have the jwt module for drf (it is called simple-jwt), and i have set up the urls as instructed in the docs, how do i fix the error, in backend side, the whole login process is supposed to be POST request:
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
```

now for react part (frontend):

````
function Login(){
    let [login,setLogin] = useState({
        email: '',
        password:''

    });
    let cookie = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    const { email, password } = login;
    function handleChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value);
        setLogin({
            ...login,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });

    }
    function handleSubmit(e){
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/token/',login,{withCredentials:true},{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRFToken': cookie,'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*','Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        }

        )
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    
    return (
        <div className="container">
        <form method='post' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <label>
                Email:
                <input type='text' name = 'email' value={email} onChange={e=>handleChange(e)} required/>

            </label>
            <label>
                Password:
                <input type='password' name = 'password' value={password} onChange={e=>handleChange(e)} required/>
            </label>
            {isLoggedin = true}
            <button type='submit'>Login</button>
        </form>
            <p className='mt-3'>
                Don't have an Account? <Link to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link>
            </p>
        </div>
    );
};



export default Login;
``` this is login component, I am getting bad request (400) error, but I cant find out why, and how to fix it? if there is anything else (more code, or more information) to add, please do not be shy to tell me, thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

The **Django 400 bad request** is caused due to many reasons which include incorrect syntax, corrupt extensions, incorrect URL, and so on.
You can try these steps :

1. May be the **ALLOWED_HOSTS** variable is not set properly :
   be sure that `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']`, since your are worked in local.
2. Clearing the cache to fix 400 bad request error. The cache can also create problems, clear the cache and try checking if the error disappears.
3. It's can also be caused by a corrupt extensions, then be aware about installed extensions you work with.